# When I click on checkbox then my bootstrap modal pop is closing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, css

I having form in modal popup with 5 checkbox with autopostback = true. When I click on one of the checkbox then my modal popup is close automatically. 
I am used update panel also and 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true); in code behind this code is reopen my modal popup. But I don't want to reopen the popup. 
How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just paste following code before page load

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  UpdatePanel updatePanel = Master.FindControl("your main Contetnt id") as UpdatePanel;
  updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
  updatePanel.ChildrenAsTriggers = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reopening the popup will always be necessary.
Autopostback causes the entire page to be reloaded and thus the states of jquery/javascript variables and modals etc. are lost.
If you don't want that you will have to use Ajax to communicate the clicking of the checkboxes and the actions they should trigger.

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't know any idea how to do that can you help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your checkboxes inside `<asp:UpdatePanel>` control:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 1" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 2" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblResults.Text = String.Empty;

    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        lblResults.Text = "Checkbox 1.";
    if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        lblResults.Text += "Checkbox 2.";
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#messageBox').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="modal fade" id="messageBox" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 1" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 2" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResults" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```